# mysql replacing columns in a table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm inserting data from a file that has 18 columns, the table that I would like to insert it into has 20 columns. 2 of those columns already contain data. How do I go about inserting the file into the table without overwriting the existing data.

below is a example of the code. note `$line .= ',,'` is appending two columns because the update wont' work unless the columns match the exact table size of 20 columns.  But the `$line .= ',,'` overwrites the data already inserted. What do i do?

```
$fcontents = file('data.txt'); 

if(mysql_error())
    echo mysql_error();

for($i=0; $i<sizeof($fcontents); $i++) 
{   
    //strip out double quotes
    $line = ereg_replace('"','',trim($fcontents[$i])); 

    $line .= ',,';

    //strip replace semi-colon with blank spaces
    $line = ereg_replace(';',' ',$line); 

    //single quote in parts records breaks replace code, removing single quote...
    $line = ereg_replace("'",'',$line); 


    //breaks apart the tab delimited row into a array
    $arr = explode(",", $line); 

    //add comma deliminted data back
    mysql_query("REPLACE INTO products VALUES ('". implode("','", $arr) ."')");


}
```

Answer (score 4):

Specify the column names:

```
REPLACE INTO products (col1, col2, ...) VALUES (val1, val2, ...)
```

See the [MySQL online manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html).

Comment: how do i specify the column names in the implode?

Comment: They go between "products" and "VALUES", no need to modify the implode!

Comment: after entering the column names and removing the line.=',,' i still have problems replacing the values. Are you sure i don't  have to do anything with the implode?

mysql_query("REPLACE INTO products (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('". implode("','", $arr) ."')");  is what i changed it do

Comment: You did change "col1, col2, col3" to be the 18 column names you're trying to insert, right?

Comment: the above code still deletes the two columns that are not specified in the replace... im confused, why would it do that?

Comment: yep, the 18 columns replace fine... it's just it deletes the two extra columns of data that is not specified in the replace.

Comment: Hrrm, I think replace deletes the row before inserting the data.. Probably need to use the update, but how do I use update with implode when I have to do set col1 = value1

Comment: It's easiest to just write out the 18 columns I guess :)  "UPDATE products SET col1 = $arr[0], col2 = ..."

Comment: yep, thatis what i ended up doing.